# Permutation Tests: How to Interpret a Non-zero-centered Null Distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, permutation-test

In a "textbook" experiment (e.g., a single treatment is randomly given to a subset of independent units, the SUTVA holds, etc.), my understanding is that a permutation test of the experiment should result in a null distribution centered around zero (since the permutations sever the correlation between a unit's receipt of treatment and their outcome).

Practically, I have seen many instances of people discussing null distributions from permutation tests that are not centered around zero (i.e., in this post -- [2-tailed permutation tests for obviously non-symmetric data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360864/2-tailed-permutation-tests-for-obviously-non-symmetric-data) -- they claim that "If the empirical null distribution is not centered at 0 but still symmetric, then intuitively, [constructing the p-value] can only occur after mean-centering the distribution").

Can someone provide the intuition as to how this non-zero centering of the null distribution can occur and/or a citation to relevant literature on this topic? For instance, is the mean of the null distribution informative of anything? Can this non-zero mean of the null distribution arise through multi-leveled randomization of treatments? etc.